# unable to retrieve link params when opening branch link inside app

Tags: android, branch.io

Our android app is a chat app. Users can paste a branch link in a chat message. When another user taps on it, we want to retrieve the link parameters to take the user to another screen.

Unfortunately, we are unable to retrieve the link parameters when we tap on such link inside the app (note that we are not using a webview), we are getting the error "Warning. Session initialisation already happened.

To force a new session, set intent extra, `branch_force_new_session`, to `true` in the `onInitFinished(@Nullable JSONObject referringParams, @Nullable BranchError error)` method.

How can we solve this? It's not obvious to me how I could pass a new intent param in that use case.

**Notes:**

Our launcher activity is singleTask
We are on [branch.io sdk](https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/) 4.3.2 
`onNewIntent()` does not seem to be called (in the code below), maybe that is the root cause for our issue.

**sample code:**

```
private Branch.BranchReferralInitListener branchReferralInitListener =
            new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInitFinished(@Nullable JSONObject referringParams, @Nullable BranchError error) {
                    ...
}

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Branch.getInstance().initSession(branchReferralInitListener, getIntent() != null ?
                getIntent().getData() : null, this);
    }
@Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        this.setIntent(intent);
        // activity will skip onStart, handle this case with reInitSession
        Branch.getInstance().reInitSession(this, branchReferralInitListener);
    }
```

Comment: Please check the following:
1. Branch.getInstance().initSession is getting called only once?
2. You are initializing Branch from your Application class - Branch.getAutoInstance(this) or using Application as android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp" in your AndroidManifest.xml
3. As a last option, give a try to use BranchSDK version 3.+ and check the behaviour. Mostly you will not face these issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with the Android SDK v4.3.2 and we are working on a resolution.
Would suggest you to try the following in the meanwhile:
When the user tries to open an app that is running in the background, we get an error for set branch_force_new_session to true.
Branch SDK gets initialised on onStart for the Launcher Activity and when the app comes foreground from the background, its on onResume. 
In this scenario, we could need to re-initialise the SDK here. 
Would request you to implement the below snippet as per Branch docs (https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/#initialize-branch)
       // activity will skip onStart, handle this case with reInitSession
        Branch.getInstance().reInitSession(this, branchReferralInitListener);

Alternatively, would suggest you to install Branch SDK v4.3.1.

Comment: thank you, this is very useful information. We did notice a few days ago that we do not get that error "Session initialization already happened" with SDK4.3.1, so we've been trying SDK 4.3.1. But so far it seems like we can retrieve the branch link params only IF the user selected 'set to always open' when he gets a prompt 'open <ourdomain>.test-app.links links with <appname>' (onNewIntent gets called in that case, just fyi). If he selects 'just once' then we can't retrieve the params (onNewIntent does not get called in that case). I will what you suggested, with onResume(), thanks!

Comment: not working for me in sdk version 5.0.11 also

Answer (score 0):

Initialized, you branch IO in application class so that it will initialize once and will not be require again

```
// Branch logging for debugging
        Branch.enableLogging();
        //Disable Device ID #2966
        Branch.disableDeviceIDFetch(true);
        // Initialize the Branch object
        BranchIOManager.setupBranchInstance(this);
        // It tells the Branch initialization to wait for the Google Play Referrer before proceeding.
        Branch.enablePlayStoreReferrer(1000L);
```

Then inside initSession() branch method use. Pass them as JSON Object to method where you can retrieve the value based on key names.

```
if (branch != null && uri != null) {
                branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchUniversalReferralInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitFinished(BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject, LinkProperties linkProperties, BranchError error) {
                        // Log.d("onInitFinished", error + "");
                        if (error == null && branchUniversalObject != null) {
                            JSONObject jBranch = branchUniversalObject.getContentMetadata().convertToJson();
                            if (!branchJSONString.equals(jBranch.toString())) {
                                //This check is applied as if we launch another mLandingScreenPhoneActivity from Branch link then app will become in loop
                                branchJSONString = jBranch.toString();
                                loadScreenFromBranchIODynamicLink(jBranch, 0);
                            }
                        }

                        if (error != null) {
                            //  //Toast.makeText(LandingScreenPhoneActivity.this, error + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, uri, this);
            }
```

Here you can get screen values

```
String screenName = referringParams.optString("screen_key");
            //Screen in app where needs to navigate
int screenIndex = referringParams.optInt("screen_index");
```